# R - Convert SpatialLines to a unique SpatialPolygon

Tags: r, line, polygon, spatial

I have a SpatialLines object that I want to convert into a SpatialPolygons object. More precisely, my goal is to transform a SpatiaLines(DataFrame in the following example) into a single polygon.

The only solution I found is with `PBSmapping` package. But I'm not really confortable with the `PolySet` concept of this package and the result is not completely satisfying.

So I'm looking for a way with 'classic' packages (`sp`, `rgeos`, `rgdal`) and their classes.

Here is my code :

```
library(sp) ; library(rgdal)
library(rgeos) ; library(maptools)

my_directory <- "" # fill with your own directory

# Load the data
my_map <- readOGR(dsn = paste0(my_directory, "Departements"),
                  layer = "LIMITE_DEPARTEMENT")

borders_map <- my_map [my_map $NATURE %in% c("Fronti\xe8re internationale",
                                             "Limite c\xf4ti\xe8re"), ]

class(borders_map) # a SpatialLinesDataFrame in this example

# Convert SpatialLinesDataFrame into SpatialPolygons
library(PBSmapping)

var_temp <- SpatialLines2PolySet(borders_map)
sp_try <- PolySet2SpatialPolygons(var_temp)

proj4string(sp_try) <- proj4string(borders_map)

class(sp_try)

plot(sp_try)
```

The file SPH "Departements" is here :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wksMnkufQPdOfSbhWoZbPKMqlcLcll_j

And the result (especially I don't understand the overlay of "two" polygons) :

[image: ThePlot]

Comment: Your code creates 81 polygons. This polygons are somehow artificial, as they represent parts of the border of France and are meaningless. What is your ultimate  goal? Are you eager to transform the SpatialLinesDataframe into one unique Polygon?

Comment: Yes, my ultimate goal is to transform the SpatiaLines(DataFrame in my example) into a single Polygon. I have modified the title and completed my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read in the DEPARTMENT dataset, and it was SpatialPolygon object. Afterwards, I combined all counties into one unique Polygon.

```
my_map <- readOGR(dsn = paste0(my_directory, "Departements"),
                  layer = "DEPARTEMENT")
border <- unionSpatialPolygons(my_map, IDs=rep(1, 96))
plot(border)
str(border,2)

 Formal class 'SpatialPolygons' [package "sp"] with 4 slots
  ..@ polygons   :List of 1
  ..@ plotOrder  : int 1
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 99226 6049647 1242375 7110524
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
```

Comment: OK, obvious way to do that... Thanks. So I will delete the question who become irrelevant. For my own understanding, how did you "know" that if you read another layer of the SPH file you will import a SP object and not a SL object ?